# How to get field value having space, hyphen in REST API in GraphQL

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server

REST API Endpoint - https://api.jikan.moe/v3/manga/13

"Alterantive version", "Side story" and "Spin-off" fields are having space and hyphen.

[image]

**common_schema.js**

```
const { gql } = require('apollo-server');

const typeDefs = gql`

    type RelatedType {
        Adaptation: [RelatedSubType]
        SideStory: [RelatedSubType]
        Character: [RelatedSubType]
        Summary: [RelatedSubType]
        Other: [RelatedSubType]
        AlternativeVersion: [RelatedSubType]
        SpinOff: [RelatedSubType]
    }

    type RelatedSubType {
        mal_id: ID
        type: String
        name: String
        url: String
    }
`;

module.exports = typeDefs;
```

If I write field value as `Spin-off` or `Alternative version` then it gives an error in terminal. `"Spin-off"` also doesn't work. I know these aren't valid but then also tried.

**manga_resolver.js**

```
module.exports = {
    Query: {
        manga: (_, { id }, { dataSources }) =>
            dataSources.mangaAPI.getMangaDetail(id)
    }
};
```

**manga.js**

```
const { RESTDataSource } = require('apollo-datasource-rest');

class MangaAPI extends RESTDataSource {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.baseURL = 'https://api.jikan.moe/v3/manga/';
    }

    async getMangaDetail(mal_id) {
        const response = await this.get(`/${mal_id}`);
        return response;
    }
}

module.exports = MangaAPI;
```

**Query** -

```
query getMangaDetail{
manga(id: 13){
    related{
      Adaptation{
        name
      }
      AlternativeVersion{
        name
      }
      SpinOff{
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Getting `null` in those fields which are having space and hyphen.

**Query result** -

```
{
"data": {
    "manga": {
      "related": {
        "Adaptation": [
          {
            "name": "One Piece"
          }
        ],
        "AlternativeVersion": null,
        "SpinOff": null
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Repository - jikan-graphql](https://github.com/GermaVinsmoke/jikan-graphql)

Comment: As an aside, while your type names should be PascalCase, your field names should be camelCase to align with current naming conventions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the spec](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-Names), names in GraphQL must follow this format:

```
/[_A-Za-z][_0-9A-Za-z]*/
```

In other words, neither spaces nor dashes are permitted. If your data source is returning property names that are formatted incorrectly, you can just provide resolvers for the fields in question:

```
const resolvers = {
  RelatedType: {
    sideStory: (parent) => {
      return parent['Side story']
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thanks for the help!